# Batches return error "No Active Batch"

Tags: 7, batch-operations

Whenever I run any functions that require a batch to run (delete users, manually check for updates, etc.), the Batch API returns an error "No Active Batch".

I have scoured the internet for pointers, and I have not been able to solve the issue.  I am not running Secure Pages.

Notes about my setup:

```
Drupal 7.39
nginx 1.8.0
PHP 5.5.28-1~dotdeb+7.1
varnish-4.0.3 revision b8c4a34
memcached 1.4.24
```

Drupal Modules:

https://gist.github.com/meinemitternacht/237410cf5a1e41bfc901

Varnish Configuration:

https://gist.github.com/meinemitternacht/438bd021d620af2032c3

Comment: if you are using [securepages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages) module then its patch is available check this [Patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/securepages-no_active_batch_error-1627326-26.patch)

Comment: I'm not running securepages.

Comment: Here is the Varnish configuration required to avoid batch errors with Drupal: sub vcl_recv { ... if (req.url ~ "^/batch") { return (pass); } ... }